# HttpWebRequest Response remains empty

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

EDIT: For some reason it all of a sudden works. Didn't change anything in the code..

I'm using a `HttpWebRequest` to get an `Xml` file from URL.
This the HttpWebRequest works perfectly on all my other pages, but on this one, it doensn't.
The text in `obj.Text` is 4015087900026 (checked it while code is running) and the text of the `string` url is http://cocktailpws.net23.net/requests/get_cocktail.php?barcode=4015087900026 , but the `response` is `null`. No exceptions are thrown or any errors. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

C#:

```
try
{
    //string urlPar = "barcode=" + obj.Text;
    string url = "http://cocktailpws.net23.net/requests/get_cocktail.php?barcode=" + obj.Text;

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
    {
       var reponse = request.EndGetResponse(r);
       XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(reponse.GetResponseStream());
       //rest of the code
    }, null);
}
catch (Exception myExc)
{
       Console.WriteLine(myExc.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `HttpClient` class, here is a working solution

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var xml =  await client.GetStringAsync("http://cocktailpws.net23.net/requests/get_cocktail.php?barcode=4015087900026");
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works as well. And it's way more clear than mine so I'm going to use it.